# Why does the same punctuation work on one html page but not the other html page with the same settings?

Tags: html, character-encoding, punctuation

Why does the same punctuation work on one page but not the other page?

Here is how the html is laid out on both pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Here is the text:
     
     Few issues seem as pressing today as women’s rights. The art exhibition “She 
     Inspires,”

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the characters "," and  " ' " dont work instead its some other combo of characters - i think my charset is the problem but Im wondering why there is this inconsistency in the first place...

Comment: UTF-8 is default character encoding in html5. Windows encoding is windows specific. Which platform are you using?

Comment: Cool I am using html5... but that UTF-8 works for windows as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is default and works everywhere.

Comment: Great thanks I will switch over everything to that...was kind of wondering why charset=windows-1252" works on the home page but not subsidiary pages, but dont really care,,,

Comment: Mark as answer if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change the charset to UTF-8, which is the default character encoding in html5.

windows-1252 works on Windows and may be limited on other platforms.

UTF-8 works everywhere and covers almost all characters and symbols.